# Question on looping over Pandas dataframe for stock market algo

Tags: python, pandas

I want to analyse a trading algo on historical stock market data with python pandas. But I learned the use of looping over large datasets isn't really fast - it's not possible with millions of rows.

So I started with boolean indexing. But I can't get it to work. Anybody has a clue? My example has 5 rows, but in reality i have 2 million rows.

I learned about the SHIFT function to take into account the values of the previous row. But that only solves the matter for just one row.

```
## data set
timehourminute=['15:25','15:30','15:35','15:40','15:45']
close=[21.02,21.05,21.10,21.22, 21.17]
signal=[False,True,True,True,False]
position=[0,0,0,0,0]
data={'timehourminute':timehourminute,'close':close, 'signal':signal,'position':position}
df=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)

## if time = 15:30 and signal = True, buy $1000 worth of stocks
subset = (df.timehourminute=='15:30') & (df.signal==True)
df.loc[subset,'position']=(1000/df.close)

## if previous row has position, keep the position if the signal is still True
df['positionprev']=df.position.shift(1)
df.position = df.signal * df[['position','positionprev']].max(axis=1)
df.position = df.position.astype(int)
```

The output is this:

```
timehourminute  close  signal  position  positionprev
0          15:25  21.02   False         0           NaN
1          15:30  21.05    True        47      0.000000
2          15:35  21.10    True        47     47.505938
3          15:40  21.22    True         0      0.000000
4          15:45  21.17   False         0      0.000000
```

The problem is I want to keep the position until the signal turns false. In this example the signal lasts 3 rows, but in reality it could last 1000 rows. How do i get the value of 47 to stay in row 3 as well?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need [`Series.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html) for missing values by conditions and forward filling missing values:

```
df['new'] = df.position.mask(df.signal & (df.position == 0)).ffill()
print (df)
  timehourminute  close  signal   position        new
0          15:25  21.02   False   0.000000   0.000000
1          15:30  21.05    True  47.505938  47.505938
2          15:35  21.10    True   0.000000  47.505938
3          15:40  21.22    True   0.000000  47.505938
4          15:45  21.17   False   0.000000   0.000000
```

Comment: That is awesome, exactly what I was looking for! Will learn more about mask and ffill